# I want to make a account generator but its giving me a 404 on request URL

Tags: python, python-requests, account

This is my code I dont really know what is the issue its giving me a 404 everytime I run the code the URL does exist.
Any help appreciated
btw im pretty new to requests
The site doesnt have much protection as of what I know also it uses cloudflare but not heavily where it checks the browser.
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

```
import requests
import randominfo
from requests.models import Response
import random
import string
import time

lenght = 15

lower = string.ascii_lowercase
upper = string.ascii_uppercase
num = string.digits
sym = string.punctuation

all = lower + upper + num + sym

temp = random.sample(all,lenght)

password = "".join(temp)

with open(path, 'r') as configFile:
    catchall = configFile.read()

login = randominfo.get_first_name() + '.' + randominfo.get_last_name() + catchall
passwordInput = password
passwordVeryfication = password

URLGet = 'https://de.afew-store.com'
url = 'https://de.afew-store.com/account/register'

RequestHeaders = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': 'https://de.afew-store.com/',
    'content-language': 'de',
    'method': 'POST',
    'server': 'cloudflare',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'path': 'account',
    'scheme': 'https',
}

getHeaders = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
    'location': 'https://de.afew-store.com/',
    'server': 'cloudflare',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'path': 'account',
    'scheme': 'https',
}


firstName = randominfo.get_first_name()
lastName = randominfo.get_last_name()

customerEmail = firstName + lastName + catchall

s = requests.session()
signup = s.get(URLGet, headers=getHeaders)


payload = {
    'form_type': 'create_customer',
    'utf8': '✓',
    'customer[tags]': 'lang:en',
    'customer[first_name]': firstName,
    'customer[last_name]': lastName,
    'customer[email]': customerEmail,
    'customer[password]': password,
}
login_info = s.post(url, headers=RequestHeaders, data=payload)


print(login_info.status_code)
```

Answer (score 2):

The host https://de.afew-store.com is unknown. Maybe you mistyped it

```
ping https://de.afew-store.com
ping: cannot resolve https://de.afew-store.com: Unknown host
```

Comment: Im stupid the only problem was to remove the 'de' before 'afew'